# How to plot a line graph from pandas dataframe using plotly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have this pandas dataframe

```
index   cath_date
0   2015    65
1   2016    88
2   2017    106
3   2018    97
0   2019Q2  120
6   2019Q1  101
17  2019Q3  48
```

I tried to plot a line graph using plotly trying this code

```
x= df['index'].values.tolist()
y= df['cath_date'].values.tolist()
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x= df['index'].astype(str).tolist(), y= y,
                                text= y,textposition= 'top center', mode='lines+markers',
                                hovertemplate='Avg: %{y} <br> Year: %{x}<extra></extra>'))
fig.update_layout(title_text='PPCI Primary Average 2015-2018',
                  xaxis= dict(dtick = 1, title=dict(text="Year"), showgrid = True), 
                  yaxis = dict(rangemode="tozero",autorange=True, title=dict(text="Average"), showgrid= True))
fig.show()
```

[this the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEQj5.png)

as you can see the values 2019Q1, 2019Q2, 2019Q3
so, what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

An x-axis of string doesn't make any sense so plotly is treating them like numbers. Of course having a Q1/2/3 doesn't make any sense as a number so we need to convert them to numbers:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

index = [2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2019.25,2019.5]
cath_date = [65,88,106,97,120,101,48]

x = index
y = cath_date

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x= x, y= y,
                                text= y,textposition= 'top center', mode='lines+markers',
                                hovertemplate='Avg: %{y} <br> Year: %{x}<extra></extra>'))
fig.update_layout(title_text='PPCI Primary Average 2015-2018',
                  xaxis= dict(dtick = 1, title=dict(text="Year"), showgrid = True), 
                  yaxis = dict(rangemode="tozero",autorange=True, title=dict(text="Average"), showgrid= True))
fig.show()
```

Now your last three data points will actually show.